# JQuery check if a domain name contains .com or .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a form where a user can enter a domain name, I want to validate if they have entered a domain that has `.com` or `.net`.

So,

```
www.example.com Or www.example.net //returns True

http://www.example.com/ Or http://www.example.net/ //returns True

www.example.au //returns False

www.example.com.au Or www.example.net.au //returns False

example.com Or example.net //returns True
```

I tried this:

```
var domain = "www.example.com";
if(domain.match(/([a-z])+\.(com|net)+/igm)) {
    console.log(domain+" valid domain");
} else {
    console.log(domain+" Invalid domain");
}
```

This works but it also shows domain `www.example.com.au` as valid.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: unfortunately there is no jquery solution to this, you'll have to use plain ol' javascript - I hope it doesn't hurt too much

Comment: @JaromandaX Thats okay, I can use javascript.

Comment: Use $ in end of regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex to check if the URL ends with domain.

```
/\.(com|net)\/?$/i
```

`$` will check if the string ends with the previous characters.

Code:

```
var domain = "www.example.com";
if (/\.(com|net)\/?$/i.test(domain)) {
    console.log(domain + " valid domain");
} else {
    console.log(domain + " Invalid domain");
}
```

Comment: @Criesto it returns true for that domain

Comment: I think there is confusion between urls and domains here. This solution won't work for a url like http://www.example.com/page If it really needs to work with any url, you need to parse the url first and extract the domain.

Answer (score 1):

A generic jquery function you can use for multiple purposes. tlds defaults to .com or .net, but you can supply an array of tld's for other uses

```
$.testDomain = function(domain, tlds) {
    return new RegExp('\\.(' + (tlds || ['com', 'net']).join('|') + ')\\/?$', 'i').test(domain);
};

console.log($.testDomain('http://www.example.com/'));
```

test for .gov

```
console.log($.testDomain('http://www.example.gov/', ['gov']));
```

of course, it doesn't have to be tacked on to jQuery, just answering the question as asked

```
var testDomain = function( ...
```

then use

```
testDomain(...
```